# Post upload in facebook's timeline by Facebook graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm new in facebook graph API. I easily post upload in FB's pages. But I want to upload in a timeline. But I got an error.

Request :

```
 POST API 

 https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/me/photos?access_token=<user_accessToken>&url=https://www.facebook.com/images/fb_icon_325x325.png&caption=Test photo upload
```

Response :

```
{
"error": {
    "message": "(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission publish_actions is deprecated",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "A6EzpIcMC9-hZcDlTPA6iPG"
}
```

}

Please, Explain to me How can I upload a post in the timeline.

Ref., https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads/

Comment: You can't. There is no API for it. You have to use the Share dialog.

Comment: You mean, Direct move in facebook app with sare dialog?

Comment: @WizKid Please, explain to me, and can you give me a deprecated proof link?

Comment: Proof link of what? The error message you getting specifically say it is deprecated and not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Posting to the user profile is not possible anymore, as the error message tells you. There is no API for it anymore, you can only use the Share Dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Changelog with deprecation info: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#4-24-2018

Comment: Can I upload in a group?

Comment: Is it still possible to post in a group?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/groups-api/common-uses#posting-on-a-group